# Cygwin alway's interpreted with Ctrl-C

Tags: cygwin

My cygwin terminal (known as Mintty) can't work, when I minimize it to the windows taskbar, and restore it, and it will receive the Ctrl-C signal, but i didn't touch any key.

This is wierd. when a long time command is running, i swith it to see wether is finishe, then it is interputed my Ctrl -C. I refresh intall it several times. it's still there.

This situation can also happened when i select some text on the terminal.

Thanks

Comment: Interesting. I don't have that problem on my system (32-bit Cygwin, 64-bit Windows 7). Incidentally, since this isn't a programming question, it's a better fit for [Superuser](http://superuser.com/); I've flagged it, and if the moderators agree it will be migrated.

Comment: Thanks. this problem is found on one of my machine, it's Win7 64. i have tried cygwin & cygwin64, both have the same problem.  Even I start the console via **c:/cygwin64/cygwin.bat**, it's have the same issue, seems it's not related with Mintty. I will recored a viedo, and ask on Superuser later.

Comment: I find the reason. it's caused by one translator software i installed, which can translate any word when you selected it.

Comment: You should post that as an answer (with more details about the translator software).

Answer (score 3):

Some translator software have the "Hyper Translate" function, which will copy texts selected then tries to translate it, the way how it copy strings is to simulate a Ctrl-C from keyboard. When using cygwin or some ssh/telnet terminal tools (e.g. SecureCRT, putty, NX Client..) and the Ctrl-C is not set as the hotkey for copy action, and you tries to select a block of texts, trouble comes.

I guess the one who asking this question is also a Chinese like me. Then, the famous software which will bring this trouble is "Youdao Dictionary".

Disabling the "Hyper Translate / HuaCiFanYi" function of the "Youdao Dictionary" is a remedy.

Answer (score 0):

As Leif Zhang mentioned, if you are using Lingoes or other dictionary you should uncheck the option **Translate Selected Text** as the following image.

[image: Lingoes Options]